# Why does my test code to pull data from process.env return null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, mocha.js, babeljs

I've got a Javascript library that stores serverside data in a redux store on the frontend. The data is cached for ten minutes by default. I'm adding a feature that makes that cache period configurable by using environment variables at build time to override the default period.

I've implemented the code on a branch here: [cachePeriod.js](https://github.com/devvmh/redux-crud-store/blob/feature/configurable-cache-period/src/cachePeriod.js)

I've written some unit tests for the file here (using mocha: [cachePeriod.spec.js](https://github.com/devvmh/redux-crud-store/blob/feature/configurable-cache-period/test/cachePeriod.spec.js)

Currently, 7 of 9 tests pass. The problem is that this code is setting `value` to null:

```
let value = process.env.CACHE_PERIOD ||
  process.env.REACT_APP_CACHE_PERIOD ||
  TEN_MINUTES
```

I'm using a shared function that takes values for CACHE_PERIOD and REACT_APP_CACHE_PERIOD. When both CACHE_PERIOD and REACT_APP_CACHE_PERIOD have values, it correctly uses the value for CACHE_PERIOD. But when CACHE_PERIOD is null and REACT_APP_CACHE_PERIOD is a value, this line sets value to `null`. I'm totally at a loss as to why.

I'm guessing the issue is either a) some quick of how javascript works on the CLI vs the browser or b) something really obvious I'm missing in the code.

The command I use to run the tests is

```
node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --reporter spec test/cachePeriod.spec.js
```

All my other env is stored on github on this branch: [feature/configurable-cache-period](https://github.com/devvmh/redux-crud-store/tree/feature/configurable-cache-period)

Any ideas?

Comment: start off by console.log them and see what value is being passed to them.

Comment: I've done a lot of console logging already. I can add it to the answer if it helps...